# Unable to access textbox value set using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am setting a taxtbox value using jquery in document.ready().
On a button click, I am trying to access its value as txtbox1.Value() but I am getting "" empty string. But if I use an alert msg I get its value alert($('txtbox1').val())

Please let me know whats the problem.
Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more code so that everyone can get a better idea of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that you may have confused two different ways to get the value of an element.

**HTML**

```
<input id="txtbox1"></input>
<button id="button1">test</button>​
```

**JS**

```
​$(​"#button1").click(function(){
    alert($("#txtbox1").val());

    //or

    alert(document.getElementById("txtbox1").value);

});​
```

The first option get the document reference using jQuery syntax `$("#txtbox1")` then uses the jQuery function [**`.val()`**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of the input.

The second option instead uses standard javascript to get a element reference via `document.getElementById("txtbox1")` and grabs the value from that object with `.value`.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YYM7J/)**

Answer (score 0):

If txtbox1 is element's id than use  `alert($('#txtbox1').val())`

You might want to read document on [jQuery Selctors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `alert($('#txtbox1').val())`

Answer (score 0):

Because its a ID its's supposed to be

`alert($('#txtbox1').val())`   .. ID should be prepended with a #

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/gTyZw/)

Comment: The problem is you are using txtbox1.Value()  .. It is supposed to be  .val() and not .value()

Answer (score 0):

If the textbox have the ID "txtbox1" you should do:

```
alert($('#txtbox1').val())
```

or

```
alert($('.txtbox1').val())
```

if that name is the class of the textbox.

Notice the '#' and the '.', the first one is for selecting id's and the second one for classes. You need that.